# Is there a way to make procedural textures not go on infinitely?

Tags: texturing, procedural

I'm looking for a solution to a problem where I need to use just a part of a procedural texture, specifically a single ring from a Wave texture, instead of the infinitely outgoing rings.

[image]

There are solutions like using various masks to limit a procedural texture to a specific area, but I need something along the lines that sort of takes the type of texture I'm using into consideration. As in my example, to limit a Wave texture to a single ring or band, or a like a Voronoi texture which would use a single "shard", or a cluster of them, and to not go on forever.

[image]

Comment: if you would show us your procedural modifier ...we could help you. Best would be a blend file so we don't have to recreate all ourselves. Which you should do because you want our help, right? So make it easy for us to help.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on why masks don't suffice in your situation?  What does success/failure look like?

Comment: Added a picture and a .blend. 
Masks would be super finicky to set up in my case, but I'm open to ideas.

Comment: Radial mask is the same as a linear gradient mask, you have to know that the equation of a circle of radius r is x²+y² = r². Or even easier, use a Vector math node set to length and a math node set to compare

Comment: @Gorgious How could I make a radial mask? Feel free to write it as an answer. Vector length may just work though.

Comment: Is it necessary that you take the Wave texture or are you just going to make a ring?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm afraid it does come down to masking, on a case-by-case basis. As [Gorgious comments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229141/is-there-a-way-to-make-procedural-textures-not-go-on-infinitely#comment387371_229141), by the time you've masked a *Wave* texture, you may as well have rolled-your-own rings... maybe something like:

[image]

*Voronoi* gives you a handle to make a mask to cell boundaries, here, around an origin of your choice:

[image]

Comment: Hey, that Voronoi screenshot just changed my brain.

Comment: Thanks! That voronoi example may just be the most useful thing I've learnt about blender yet. I wish you could do that sort of thing with every procedural texture.

Comment: @Geri Thanks! The reason you can do it with Voronoi is that it's fundamentally based on points (random per cell)  in a grid, and it knows where those points are. The others tend to be continuous functions of the whole, undivided space. You can often assemble your own versions, for more control.

Answer (score 12):

There is no common interface of texture nodes with "start at" and "end at" inputs. Therefore you need to limit the influence of each node with a method specific to that particular node. There's no general trick that I'm aware of, other than "masking".

In case of your particular problem:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I really wish procedural textures had a "start at" and "end at" values. They could maybe even accept BW values, so it wouldn't a simple radial thing.

Answer (score 6):

Since you need only one ring, maybe a "ring shader node" is the right solution for you:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment:  https://i.imgur.com/9dtG65A.png

Comment: Thanks! It's a good solution, but I need the feathered edges as well.

Comment: @Geri Do `min(0, -abs(sqrt(x**2+y**2)-ringradius)+ringthickness)/ringthickness` instead then. It will give you a normalized linear feather, like the wave shader, to which you can also apply a root or exponent. …I don't think there's a "Min" option for the `Math` node, so you'll have to emulate it with "Greater Than" or a `MixRGB`/"Lighten" instead.

Comment: Thanks! .. Uhm.. could you show that with nodes? xD

Comment: @Geri just use the setup Robin Betts presented, if you don't like color ramps, you can use math>ping-pong instead.