# What does the distance in Voronoi texture node do?

Tags: materials

[image]

I was following a youtube tutorial but I could not find what the distance in Voronoi Texture node do here.

The video tutorial link:
https://youtu.be/__Q5X1S0EEg?t=148

Comment: Some nodes like the Voronoi have changed between the Blender versions 2.81 and 2.83. In the tutorial Blender 2.93 is used. It looks like you have an older Blender version. In Blender 2.83 the Voronoi node looks like [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/editors/texture_node/types/textures/voronoi.html?highlight=voronoi) - (not sure if this is really 2.83 and the documentation is up to date?) Try to use the option "Actual Distance" and use the Color output? Or update Blender ;-) Here is a short overview of the changes: https://youtu.be/F2edriq1PAQ

Comment: @Blunder thanks for your comment and my blender is 3.1

Comment: Are you asking what the distance output produces?  Voronoi generates a random array of points, called features.  "Distance" is a measure of how close a point in space is to a particular feature.  How it is computed depends on the 3rd input parameter to the texture.  In Blender, the feature closest to the point is used.  See [Voronoi Texture Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/voronoi.html) which will lead you to [Worley Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worley_noise) that contains a better description.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/229146/110840

Answer (score 4):

[Blender 3.1's Voronoi node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/voronoi.html) makes procedural [Voronoi diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).  When the F1 feature is selected the Distance output of the node makes a grayscale diagram with the darkest points the location of each cell's seed, and the bright lines the furthest away from the seeds as calculated by the selected metric (Euclidean by default):

[image]

The tutorial you've referenced uses the Voronoi node's Distance output as a heightmap to help create a mountainous terrain, with the bright cell borders making high ridges and the dark cell interiors making valleys:

[image]

Please note that the Voronoi nodes above are identical, I've used two here for clarity -- best practice would be to use the same Voronoi node for both the Surface and Displacement branches.

[image]